# How to change point size in qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In regular R plot, I can make points smaller or larger by changing `cex` argument. How do I do this if I use ggplot, please? In particular, I am making ggplot and want to make the points smaller. Thank you!

Thanks to those who commented. But I do not see how to use `size` for qqplot. My code is as follows.

```
qplot(sample=Shape, data=shape.mop, colour=Type) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  geom_point(size=0.5)
```

Comment: Use the `size` parameter. See `?geom_point`

Comment: If you prefer a web interface, see http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can settle the size of points with parameter `size` inside `qplot` call, using function`I`:

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars)
```

[image]

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, size=I(0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Please see my update. I do not see how size would work here.

Comment: @20824, see my edit, based on the [first answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-January/266550.html) from a simple google search with "qplot size point" as keywords...

Comment: Sorry, the command is indeed qplot. But it can be used to plot QQ-plot (quantile-quantile plot).

Comment: @20824, when you tag a question with "ggplot2", title it with "ggplot" and then "qplot", how do you expect anyone to understand that what you really need is something that works on qqplot ?... Please edit your question with a reproducible example and what doesn't work, because my code does work with `qplot`... else, it's really hard to help you (and I promise I'm trying hard to...)